# How can I define Optional dependecies for seperate bundles?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, namespaces

I will explain with an example:
There are 2 bundles : `Foo\SecurityBundle` and `Foo\MenuBundle`.
`Foo\MenuBundle` has Menu class that looks like this:

```
namespace Foo\MenuBundle;

use Foo\SecurityBundle\MenuSecurer; //note this
class Menu{
    protected $securer;
    public function __construct(MenuSecurer $securer = null){
        $this->securer = $securer;
    }

    public function buildMenu(){
        //build the $menu ...
        //...
        if($this->securer != null)
            $securer->secure($menu);
    }

}
```

---

the security bundle will automatically inject the $menuSecurer if it is installed,
however the problem is When the security bundle is not installed then it's classes aren't defined either, so i can't `use Foo\SecurityBundle...` in the MenuBundle even though I don't really use it.what's the correct way around this?

Comment: Clarification: The question is mostly regarding the use statement and the used but potentially not declared Interface.

Comment: There might not be a good solution to that. You could either make sure your bundle has a dependency on the one that contains the interface, or you could split the interfaces off into a separate bundle altogether and require that one. Or perhaps I'm not understanding the real issue correctly.

Comment: @ChadSikorra : yes that is my problem indeed.What I currently do: the create two seperate services, one without the optional dependency and one without.Then I change the service definition, using a Compiler Pass in the Dependee Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the symfony docs dealing with this this situation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection

> *If you have optional dependencies for a class, then "setter injection"
>   may be a better option.*

According to this your class might look like this:

```
namespace Foo\MenuBundle;

class Menu{
    protected $securer;

    public function setSecurer($securer) {
        $this->securer = $securer;
    }

    public function buildMenu(){
        //build the $menu ...
        //...
        if($this->securer != null)
            $securer->secure($menu);
    }

}

# config.yml
menu_service:
    class: Foo\MenuBundle\Menu
    calls:
        - [setMailer, ["@securer"]]
```

Something like this...
Unfortunately you still cannot have a use statement without an interface you know is existing.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to go about this, but I think a good approach would be to add a configuration setting for the class/service to be injected into the constructors first argument.

For example, in the `Foo\MenuBundle\Menu` class (assuming this is defined as a service already), you could add an additional item to the bundle's configuration to define a default service for the `$securer`, then optionally override it in the config if desired.

In the configuration class (`DependecyInjection\Configuration.php`):

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('foo_menu');
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('service')
                ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('menu_securer')->defaultValue('foo_security.menu_securer')->end()
               >end()
            ->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

In the extension class (`DependecyInjection\FooMenuExtension.php`):

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

// ...

public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

    // This is what sets 'foo_menu.menu_securer' to the service you want
    foreach ($config['service'] as $key => $service) {
        $container->setAlias($this->getAlias() . '.' . $key, $service);
    }

    $loader->load('services.xml');

    $container->getDefinition('foo_menu.menu.menu')
        ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference('foo_menu.menu_securer'));
}
```

And your service definition would just look something like this...

```
<service id="foo_menu.menu.menu" class="%foo_menu.menu.menu.class%">
  <argument /> <!-- foo_menu.menu_securer -->
</service>
```

Now in your `config.yml` you can just switch out the service you want to use by defining it in under...

```
foo_menu:
    service:
        menu_securer: 'some_other.service'
```

Edit: Regarding the type hinting, as mentioned by Markus, it would probably be a good idea to implement an interface that the `$securer` must implement.